# Errors when adding Rajawali Framework to project

Tags: android, rajawali

I planned to test the OpenGL framework Rajawali.
When I follow the tutorial on how to set it up I do the following:

1. Create an Android project.
2. Import the Rajawali source code. As soon as that is done I get the error:

**"The method setOffsetNotificationsEnabled(boolean) is undefined for the type WallpaperService.Engine  Wallpaper.java  /Rajawali-master/src/rajawali/wallpaper line 312".**

and

**"The method setOffsetNotificationsEnabled(boolean) of type Wallpaper.WallpaperEngine must override or implement a supertype method Wallpaper.java /Rajawali-master/src/rajawali/wallpaper line 310".**

1. When I try to link the Rajawali project with the project I created I get errors:

**The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library "D:\Prosjekter\Rajawij\Rajawali-master\bin\rajawali-master.jar".**

and

**"The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved".** <--- Should go away as soon as the other errors are fixed I guess.

Anyone have experience with Rajawali or have an idea on how I get solve the problems?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Rajawali extensively for a few months. I would ensure you have all Google APIs installed up to 4.2+ Also be sure to grab the most current Master branch from their github.  The links on the tutorial pages are out of date. https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali

They moved away from using a compiled JAR and instead are encouraging linking it as a library to your project. When you do that be sure to clean all projects and make sure that you don't have any files or folders in your project that are duplicates of those in Rajawalis libs folder.

Good luck, its a fantastic framework.